# Getting "Empty entity body is not allowed for create method request" when trying to post an image using LinkedIn API with Python

Tags: python, python-requests, linkedin-api

I am following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/images-api?view=li-lms-2023-06&tabs=http) documentation to post an image on LinkedIn using their API. I have initialised the upload, as the documentation instructs, and that works as intended. But when I am trying to actually upload the image, as instructed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/vector-asset-api?view=li-lms-2023-06&tabs=http#upload-the-image), I am getting the following response -

```
{
    "message": "Empty entity body is not allowed for create method request",
    "status": 400
}
```

My code is as follows -

```
def image_post(self, image_title, image_url, return_urn=False):
        url = f"{LINKEDIN_URL}images?action=initializeUpload"

        payload = {
            "initializeUploadRequest": {
                "owner": self.__linkedin_urn
            }
        }

        response_init = requests.post(url=url, headers=self.__headers, json=payload)

        LOGGER.info(response_init.json())
        LOGGER.info(response_init.status_code)

        try:
            response_json = response_init.json()
            upload_url = response_json['value']['uploadUrl']
            image = response_json['value']['image']

            mimetype, _ = mimetypes.guess_type(image_url)
            headers = {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer Redacted',
                'Content-Type': mimetype if mimetype else 'application/octet-stream'
            }

            response = requests.post(url=upload_url, headers=headers,
                                     files={"file": (image_url, self.__media_to_bytes(image_url))})

            LOGGER.info(response.json())
            LOGGER.info(response.status_code)

            if response.status_code != 201:
                LOGGER.error("Image Upload Failed")
                return Response(content=json.dumps({"message": "Failed to upload image"}),
                                status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

            if not return_urn:
                self.__payload = {
                    "author": self.__linkedin_urn,
                    "commentary": self.request.get('commentary'),
                    "visibility": "PUBLIC",
                    "distribution": {
                        "feedDistribution": "MAIN_FEED",
                        "targetEntities": [],
                        "thirdPartyDistributionChannels": []
                    },
                    "content": {
                        "media": {
                            "title": image_title,
                            "id": image
                        }
                    },
                    "lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED",
                    "isReshareDisabledByAuthor": False
                }
            else:
                return image
        except Exception as e:
            LOGGER.error(e)
            return Response(content=json.dumps(response_init.json()), status_code=response_init.status_code)
```

This is self.__headers

```
self.__headers = {
            'Authorization': f'Bearer {self.__access_token}',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Linkedin-Version': '202304'
        }
```

This is the code to actually make the image post on LinkedIn.

```
def __create_post(self, post_type):
        url = f"{LINKEDIN_URL}posts"
        post = Posts(self.request, self.__linkedin_urn, self.__get_headers(), post_type=post_type)
        self.__response = requests.post(url=url, headers=self.__get_headers(), json=post.get_payload())
```

The `image_post` method is part of the `Posts` class.

I would really appreciate it if someone could guide me to do this right.